# How to know if the computer is getting enough power?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power, ups

I have a UPS (650VA) and connected few devices including a laptop to it. I need to know is there a software or any tool or any way that I can know the devices are getting enough power? And also is this 650VA can handle multiple laptops? And how much really is this 650VS in watts?

Comment: For a UPS at 120 Volts (North America), Watts = Power Factor time VA.  If the power factor is (say) 90 % for  an efficient UPS, Watts is about 585. Then you need to add up the gross watts of each device and your UPS should be rated for about 150% of gross load to permit smooth transition and load growth.

Comment: I have two chargers that is sum of 300W. So is this UPS can handle it?

Comment: Yes . Your UPS is very adequate. Should I make my comment an answer with your additional information?

Comment: Alot of UPS can be connected to via USB or Ethernet and allow you (through extra software) to check the load on the UPS. Check the vendor webpage to see if there is anything like that for your UPS.

Comment: @John Yes sure. Thank you very much

Comment: @Silbee Sure I will check. Thank you very much

Comment: *"And how much really is this 650VS in watts?"* -- That depends on how reactive or resistive your load (what is being powered) is.  See https://superuser.com/questions/348103/pc-watts-usage-comparison/348104#348104

Comment: That is why I used an estimate. Of course it depends. Anyone knows that. But estimates are good and useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I have a UPS (650VA) and connected few devices including a laptop to
> it.
>
> I need to know is there a software or any tool or any way that I can
> know the devices are getting enough power? And also is this 650VA can
> handle multiple laptops?  Follow up: total Laptop draw 300 Watts.
>
> And how much really is this 650VS in watts?

**To determine Watts:** For a UPS at 120 Volts (North America), Watts = Power Factor time VA. If the power factor is (say) 90 % for an efficient UPS, Watts is about 585.

The calculation above is just an estimate but that will suffice in most situations.

**Total Capacity :**  Then you need to add up the gross watts of each device and your UPS should be rated for about 150% of gross load to permit smooth transition and load growth. The term "gross load" here is to ensure that the top rate load is used. Average or representative loads will be smaller and the top load will be best to determine overall rating.

**Your load:**  You added that total load is about 300 watts so yes, your UPS will handle the loads.

Comment: *"If the power factor is (say) 90 % for an efficient UPS ..."* -- The power factor would depend on the electrical load, not the UPS.  What are *"gross watts"*?  Are there also "net watts"?

Comment: I used the term to make sure of the top load (again an estimate).  It seems to me in an answer like this that reasonable estimates are fine. Maybe not for you, but good enough for very many of us.